# Why is a quarkonium any different from a meson?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, mesons

Quarkonium states are bound states of a quark-antiquark pair but so do the mesons. What is the difference between a quarkonium (e.g., charmonium, and bottomonium) and a meson then? Why use a separate name for $c\bar{c}$ and $b\bar{b}$ bound states other than some meson state?

Comment: I've removed a comment that answered the question. Please post answers as answers.

Comment: -1 The opening lines of Wikipedia answers your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarkonium  Quarkonium is a flavorless meson whose constituents are a heavy quark and its own antiquark, making it a neutral particle and the antiparticle of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkonium states are a type of meson state. There are other meson states, e.g charged mesons.

Comment: This looks more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @descheleschilder It was originally a comment but got deleted for being an answer.

Comment: Your history shows it was an answer the first time.

Comment: it was a comment.

Comment: But look here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/525170/timeline

Comment: it doesn't show mine or Rob's comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103405/discussion-between-bemjanim-and-descheleschilder).

Answer (score -2):

I'll answer in the most simple way:

Quarkonium (like positronium in the electromagnetic case) consists of two anti-particles (like an electron and a positron in positronium). The quarks inside quarkonium are anti-particles of each other.

The properties of one quark are opposite (anti) to the properties of the other. Which is to say, the colors **and** electric charge. 
In mesons, you have indeed two anti-particles but the charges don't have to be opposite (in contrast to their color). After all, there exists charged mesons.

So charmonium or bottomonium, in wich **all** charges have to be opposite, are different from the corresponding mesons, in which only the colors have to be opposite.

So you could say, both are special kinds of mesons.

See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarkonium) Wikipedia article.

Comment: Your second paragraph is badly messed up. At valence level the constituiends of the meson *do* have to  have opposite color (because mesons are unconfined and must be colorless), but they are not required to be opposite in electric charge (which is why some mesons are non-neutral).

Comment: For a bound system to be colorless as a whole the colors must also be the opposite.

Comment: @dmckee---ex-moderatorkitten Kitten?  What are constitui ends?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 You're right. I edited.